# How to get the visited web url list in c#?

Tags: c#, url, proxy, tracking, visited

I need to track all urls which is visited from a particular system. I think It need to set a proxy server for this. Can anyone help me to setup a proxy server using c# code for my windows based application and then how can I take visited urls using this proxy.

For example if a user visit google.com,yahoo.com,fb.com etc from IE and stackoverflow.com,orkut.com from any other browser. Then I need to track all these url from my client application. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
      Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

and

```
 Request.UrlReferrer
```

this will gives you a previously visited url.

Comment: I need to track all visited urls from my windows client app. For example if a user visit google.com,yahoo.com,fb.com etc from IE and stackoverflow.com,orkut.com from any other browser. Then I need to track all these url from my client application. Is it possible?